# Conflicting constructors due to optional parameter

Tags: c#

I have two contructors that are conflicting and I don't know how I could handle this situation.

```
public NotFoundError(string name, object key, int code = 0)
: base($"Entity '{name}' ({key}) was not found.")
{
    Code = code;
}

public NotFoundError(string message, int code = 0)
    : base(message)
{
    Code = code;
}
```

If I do the following:

```
throw new NotFoundError(nameof(Customer), request.Id);
```

It picks the second constructor instead of the first. I know that it happens because it could match with either of them. However, I would like to keep the first constructor because in 99% of the cases, the message will look like that and I don't want to add the message to every exception. For both cases I need the ability to overwrite the error code.

Comment: Is  `new NotFoundError(nameof(Customer), (object)request.Id);` an option?

Comment: I guess that could be a possibility but if there is a better option and I can avoid the object cast everywhere, I would prefer that.

Comment: I could also do ```new NotFoundError(nameof(Customer), key: request.Id);```

Comment: Still not ideal because if a new developer forgets that, it will call the wrong constructor

Comment: Can't you just change the key type in your constructor from object to string? As the key is just becoming a string in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use some factory methods if it's not too cumbersome. Make those ctors private:

```
public class NotFoundError
{
   // private ctors
   public static NotFoundError ForEntity(string name, object key, int code = 0)
   {
     return new NotFoundError(name, (object)key, code);
   }

   public static NotFoundError WithGenericMessage(string message, int code = 0)
   {
     return new NotFoundError(message, code);
   }
}
```

Comment: This has the added bonus of being more readable at the point of call.

Comment: So then I would call the static functions instead of the constructors directly?

Comment: @TomelSafadi Correct. Also in some cases you can make the constructors private and only allow construction via the static methods, if that makes sense for your usage.

Answer (score 2):

Use [named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601009/when-are-named-arguments-useful).  The compiler will choose the constructor with the matching names.

```
throw new NotFoundError(name: nameof(Customer), key: request.Id);
```

or

```
throw new NotFoundError(message: "Hello world");
```

Comment: Thanks, I already added that solution to the comments of my question. However, new developers could miss this and use the wrong constructor by accident. Still a vaild answer though!